# Track Which user has updated which fields of any models?

Tags: django, django-admin, tracking

How do I log which user has performed what changes(field value) in any of model?

The way I tried:

1. Write code in the pre_save signal. In that, I am getting the old and new value, but request object(for current login user) and list of updated fields are not getting.
2. Write code in Django Forms save(), but same issue can fetch request object(current login user).

Comment: Rather I say, history of any model with old and new value of fields changed and by whom

Comment: You can use `django-simple-history` for this. This will create an extra table with the historical model records, and will for views, record through middleware the user that triggered the view that changed these models.

Comment: It is only showing the list of fields updated, not the value.
One way through it is after save, they are comparing old and new..but it is almost impossible to write that code after every save.

Comment: no, `django-simple-history` will save an entire copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might consider using [**`django-simply-history`** [readthedocs]](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). You can add this app to the `INSTALLED_APPS` and in the `MIDDLEWARE`:

```
# settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ...
    'simple_history',
    # ...
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    # ...
    'simple_history.middleware.HistoryRequestMiddleware',
    # ...
]
```

The middleware is then used to track the user that triggered a view which resulted in changes to models "with a history".

You can add a history manager to a model like:

```
from django.db import models
from simple_history.models import HistoricalRecords

class SomeModel(models.Model):
    some_field = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    history = HistoricalRecords()
```

It will add copies of the `SomeModel` with a timestamp and a reference to the user that made the change in an extra table.

See the [*User tracking section* [readthedocs]](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_tracking.html) for more info.

Comment: I just tried Django simple history, but it is logging all fields irrespective of which fileds changed.

Comment: @Jamin: that is correct, since fields can have different types, it would be hard to store these all in the same field, since something is not an integer and string at the same time. You can however quite easily calculate the difference by converting two model objects to a dictionary, and calculate the symmetric dictionary difference.

Comment: yeah, ultimately I think it is the best solution as no read operations are performed over it regularly on server.We need for tracking purpose only in case required.

Comment: Just one thing comes out of mind, as possibly this fields change tracking is for tracking only and no statistics are performed over it.so isn't we store them in JSON fields with only value of fields that are changed?

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider  [django-dirtyfields](https://django-dirtyfields.readthedocs.io/en/develop/)

This lets you obtain a dict of field values that have been altered since the model was instantiated. You could subclass the model `save` method, and write the current user and the altered fields to a logfile or save a logging model. It would also allow you to decide that a subset of possible fields or changes thereto are worthy of being logged, and ignore other changes.